# Apply endDate to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to provide an EndDate when the MainAccountNum already exist. The endDate should be applied to the MainAccountNumb with the earliest startDate.

So If I have a create table statement like this:

```sql
   Create Table ods.CustomerId(
    ScreenDate INT NOT NULL,
    CustomerNum nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    MainAccountNum nvarchar(40) not null,
    ServiceNum nvarchar(40) not null,
    StartDate datetime not null,
    EndDate datetime not null,
    UpdatedBy nvarchar(50) not null);
```

and say I encounter something in the `CustomerNum, MainAccountNum, StartDate, and EndDate` like below:

```
1467823,47382906,2019-08-26 00:00:00.000, Null
1467833,47382906,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000, null
```

When the second record is inserted with that same MainAccountNum the first record should get the startDate of the New Record. The startDate has a default constraint as GetDat() so in the end it should look like:

```
1467823,47382906,2019-08-26 00:00:00.000,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000
1467833,47382906,2019-09-06 00:00:00.000, null
```

Please Provide code examples of how this can be accomplished

I would like to apply an update to the current records in my table that do not have an `endDate` but have this same situation. How would I apply that update to where I give the previous record an `endDate` please provide me with code to solve this issue. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CustomerId table has EndDate as not null, how did they end up being null. Anyway try this:

```
update CustomerId
set EndDate = (select min(t2.StartDate) from CustomerId t2
where t2.MainAccountNum = t1.MainAccountNum and t2.StartDate > t1.StartDate)
from CustomerId t1
where t1.EndDate is null
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, are you looking for a trigger function that will update all rows with null `EndDate` fields and the same `MainAccountNum` as a newly inserted row?

if so, the following should work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cust_trg
ON CustomerId
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE CustomerId
  SET EndDate = inserted.StartDate
  WHERE EndDate IS NULL AND MainAccountNum = inserted.MainAccountNum AND StartDate = (SELECT MIN(StartDate) FROM CustomerId WHERE MainAccountNum = inserted.MainAccountNum AND EndDate IS NULL)
END;
```

Note that with the schema as written there should be no null values in `EndDate` column, so unless the schema is changed this trigger will never fire.

Comment: I would like to update only the previous record with an EndDate. So the current record with the same MainAccountNumber should have a null EndDate while the previous record should have an endDate and I would like to give it an endDate of the Current Record startDate.

Comment: But also there are many of these in the table currently and where ever the CustomerNum changed but the MainAccountNumber is the same we should give an endDate to the previous record the one with the earliest startDate that has no endDate

Comment: How are the columns ordered, in order to apply this condition? I have updated the query on the assumption that they are ordered by StartDate.

Comment: I would like to order it by ScreenDate as it is a primary key in my Table so basically what I would like to see is when we grab a MainAccountNumber that is the same as another record I would like to give an endDate to the previous record by giving it the Start Date of the current record. So if the previous record has an EndDate of null give it the startDate of the new record